# LVM encrypted LUKS on SSD - issue reverting to snapshots

Tags: ssd, lvm, luks, trim

- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
- SSD is only drive (/dev/sda)
- /dev/sda1 is boot partition
- /dev/sda5 is encrypted LUKS partition
- logical volumes sit on top of the LUKS partition

Reverting to snapshots seems to work (the reverted system appears as it should), but the process yields a BLKDISCARD fail. In the following terminal, I run lvconvert --merge from a live ISO session.

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo lvconvert --merge /dev/vg1/lvsnapshot14
Merging of volume lvsnapshot14 started.
lvroot: Merged: 92.7%
lvroot: Merged: 100.0%
Merge of snapshot into logical volume lvroot has finished.
/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: BLKDISCARD ioctl at offset 121333874688 size 3221225472 failed: Operation not supported.
Logical volume "lvsnapshot14" successfully removed
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$
```

I thought this might be related to TRIM, but I do have TRIM enabled at all levels:

- filesystem via /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim
- lvm via /etc/lvm/lvm.conf
- dm-crypt via /etc/crypttab

And manually running trim is successful.

Any ideas on what's driving the failure?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The problem is that while I have TRIM support enabled at the encryption level in the system, I did not have it enabled in the live session.

I was using `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 sda5_crypt` prior to running `lvconvert --merge` as described in the question. Trim support is not enabled here, thus when BLKDISCARD runs after the snapshot is merged, it fails.

The solution is to use `cryptsetup luksOpen --allow-discards /dev/sda5 sda5_crypt`. This enables TRIM support at the encryption level. This can be verified with `dmsetup table /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt --showkeys` - the result should show "allow_discards" at the end.

Executing `lvconvert --merge` after this works fine:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo lvconvert --merge /dev/vg1/lvsnapshot14
Merging of volume lvsnapshot14 started.
lvroot: Merged: 95.6%
lvroot: Merged: 100.0%
Merge of snapshot into logical volume lvroot has finished.
Logical volume "lvsnapshot14" successfully removed
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$
```